# android.app.Application invoking ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android

I have a static class which extends android.app.Application (**HireApplication**) which is doing a lot of my background work. I create AsyncTasks here, I store the largest data objects that my application uses. I'm writing this code in the Application class so that I can reuse it between separate activities for Phones and Tablets.

This feels like the right way to layout my app, but now I have a problem. An AsyncTask has finished and needs to run notifyDataSetChanged on an ArrayAdapter within a Fragment (**ListFragment**).

Here is my solution:

**ListFragment:**

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), HireApplication.myList);
    HireApplication.myListAdapter = myListAdapter; // Tell the application where the ListView is so that it can notifyDataSetChanged
}
```

**HireApplication:**

```
public static ArrayAdapter<BikeStation> stationListAdapter = null;

private static void asyncTaskCompleteCallback() {
    {...}
    myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now, this works... but it doesn't feel right. I am giving the Application a reference back to a UI element which sounds like it's a bit tightly coupled, but I don't know a better way to do this.

Is there a better way of my Application notifying my ArrayAdapter or Fragment that it should take some action to update the UI with fresh data?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing looks wrong to me... if you are using fragments and adapters, you should be using LoadManager instead of AsyncTasks. Also, putting everything on your Application looks like a poor solution to the problem you want to solve; it will lead to posible memory leaks and does not feel right.

Comment: hahahahaha, yeah, you are right XD, I had to say it though :)

Comment: @Cristian I will look at Loaders, but regarding not coding into Application... I have struggled to understand where in an Android app to put A) data refreshed in the background used by multiple Activities / Fragments, B) code abstracted from any Activity or Fragment that can be reused based on the device and layout. What can you suggest?

Comment: What Android developers from Google recommend is to use either findFragmentByXXXX methods to update fragments from another place, OR use getActivity() and cast it to the activity you want to update activity. Either way is "valid" from their point of view, and you should actually not need anything else.